# UA PhoneGap 2.0 plugin not initializing correctly on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, object, cordova, urbanairship.com

I am trying to implement push notifications in my iOS PhoneGap 2.0 app with the newly released Urban Airship plugin. When I load the index.html from the provided sample app into my project everything works perfectly. However, when I use my app's index.html the `push` variable doesn't have access to its prototype functions. Specifically, in the *sample* app:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    push = window.PushNotification;
    console.log(typeof window.PushNotification); => 'function'
    console.log(typeof push);                    => 'object'
```

But the same code in *my* app yields:

```
    console.log(typeof push); => 'function'
```

Thus `push.enablePush()` or any other prototype functions are not callable. I have tried workarounds but they end up breaking functionality with device registration. I have no idea why this occurs, though I suspect it may be a conflict with another plugin or code that is executed before the `deviceready` event is fired.

While I'm sure the cause is a very specific problem, I don't really understand in general how assigning a variable to a function object in itself will cause the variable to store an instantiated object. Isn't that what `new` is for? Why does it work in their code but not mine?

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to follow up with you on this from the UA team.

Take a look at the sample `index.html` (line 20) and `PushNotification.js`
(line 261).  The way `index.html` accesses the plugin is like this:

```
push = window.pushNotification
```

Note the *camelCase* on `pushNotification`, as opposed to `PushNotification` in the
stackoverflow question.

In `PushNotification.js`, we're initializing the plugin by calling:

```
window.pushNotification =  new PushNotification();
```

So `PushNotification` is indeed a function, just the function that the plugin uses to bootstrap itself.

Correcting the case should solve this problem.

Let me know if this resolves the issue.